# How to stick to one network diagram layout?

Tags: python, networkx

Would it be possible to not update the position of nodes and edges of the network diagram using NetworkX?
When I run the following script, the network diagram keeps updating.

```html
nx.draw(G, node_size=10, node_color="gray")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `networkx.drawing.layout` API to create positions for the nodes.  All of the layouts take a `seed` parameter that is used for randomizing the initial positions.  If you set `seed` to a fixed value, you should always generate the same positions.

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.petersen_graph()
pos = nx.spring_layout(g, seed=777)

nx.draw(g, pos=pos, node_size=10, node_color='gray')
```

You can play with the seed number to get a layout that you like, then just keep using it.